# Using conditional logic in MVC Razor to create dynamic DIV tags. Tags not matching up

Tags: html, razor, intellisense

I'm having some formatting issues with my code, in which I am looping through a collection of objects, and trying to produce nested DIV containers.  The complexity arises, I believe, in the Razor engine's attempt at trying to match up my dynamically-issued CLOSING div tags with the opening ones. Can someone help me determine what the expected behavior is in the following code, which mimics my own, but is greatly simplified for demonstration purposes.

In this example, I would like one big OUTER DIV with a border, which contains 3 smaller divs of varying sizes (for the sake of identification).  What's happening for me is the FIRST CLOSING DIV tag I hit (inside the loop; at the end) gets applied to the OUTER DIV, but I want it applied to the LARGE DIV tag within the loop.  I want my FINAL DIV tag (outside the loop) to be applied to the big OUTER DIV tag.

The result is that my 3 INNER DIV tags are created outside of the OUTER DIV tag, and not nested inside of it.

I would just like to know how Razor decides which DIV tag belongs to which closing DIV tag, and whether or not the developer has any control over this. Any ideas?

```
@:<div class="myOuterDivWithBorder">

for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
   if (j == 0)
   {
      @:<div class="largeDiv">
   }
   else if (j == 1)
   {
      @:<div class="mediumDiv">
   }
   else if (j == 2)
   {
      @:<div class="smallDiv">
   }

   @:</div>
}

@:</div>


--Here's a glimpse into some of my actual code located within my for loop. Hopefully
--this illustrates why I feel I am unable to position both my opening and closing DIVs
--within the same scope ({}).
    iCurrentDivSize = GetDivSize(question.Type.ToLower(), options);

    if (iAvailableDivSpace == 3)
    {
        //Begin a new div.
        @:<div class="wrapDivLarge">
    }
    else  //iAvailableDivSpace is 1 or 2
    {
        if (iCurrentDivSize > iAvailableDivSpace)
        {
            //First, close the previous OUTER div, and begin a new div.
            @:</div>
            @:<div class="wrapDivLarge">
            iAvailableDivSpace = 3;
        }
    }

    //No new OUTER div tag; just new INNER div tag
    switch (iCurrentDivSize)
    {
        case 1:
            @:<div class="wrapDivSmall">                    
            break;
        case 2:
            @:<div class="wrapDivMedium">
            break;
    }

    iAvailableDivSpace = iAvailableDivSpace - iCurrentDivSize;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of writing out the entire tags, you only modify what actually changes:

```
@{
  var divClasses = new string[] { "largeDiv", "mediumDiv", "smallDiv" };
}

<div class="myOuterDivWithBorder">
@foreach (var divClass in divClasses)
{
  <div class="@divClass">
  </div>
}
</div>
```

A more *hacky* fix to your code would be (NOT DRY) the following.  The problem you are experiencing is that intellisense does not *run* your code, so it cannot figure out that no matter which if statement runs, you *currently* always get a beginning tag.  The only real fix for intellisense is to put the closing tag in the same programming scope (ie {} ).

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
   if (j == 0)
   {
      @:<div class="largeDiv">
      @:</div>
   }
   else if (j == 1)
   {
      @:<div class="mediumDiv">
      @:</div>
   }
   else if (j == 2)
   {
      @:<div class="smallDiv">
      @:</div>
   }

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid my code is a bit more complex. It inspects each div content, and decides whether it is large, medium or small content, and assigns the appropriate class to it.  The idea is to conserve space by fitting up to 3 DIVs within each OUTER DIV. Inside this OUTER DIV, I can fit 3 smalls, 1 small and 1 medium, or 1 large. So this evaluation is being done in a loop, and has opening/closing div tags, as you have depicted. It's just assigning the first closing div it finds to my OUTER DIV, closing it prematurely. Is there any way to force a closing DIV tag to close a SPECIFIC opening DIV tag?

Comment: Thanks Erik. I don't think I am able to contain my opening/closing DIV tags in the same scope, unless you see something I don't. I posted a snippet of my actual code below my example above.  What can you gleen from that?  Am I out of luck?

Comment: I don't think there is enough of your real code to refactor it for intellisense.